# ListBox and WinForms application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

I have a windows form1 application. This form1 has a click button. When the button is clicked some events handler are created in the click-button method. In the SendText event handler method I a create and show a second Form2 where i want to print a string value met in form1.

The problem is the fact that in my ListBox I see just one string and not all of them (I am consecutively sending strings). Why? Plus there are no additional Form2 forms created and shown when a new event handler arrives.

In Form1 this is the way i am calling form2:

```
public void Send(string body, string name)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2(body);
    form2.Text = name;
    form2.ShowDialog ();
} 

public  void OnMessage(first val, second vall)
{
    send(string val1, string va2);
}
```

Form2 contains:

```
public Form2(string s)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    listBox1.Items.Add(s);
}

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

2 Questions:

1. How can i create multiple Form2 forms each time the handler is activated (using threads, no?)?
2. If first val is the same when a new handler arrives how can I activate the form2 that is already on the screen and add a new item in the ListBox1?

Please provide examples, if possible.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm afraid, I don't have any clue what you are looking for. And also if you have more than one discrete questions plz ask them separately!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i got this right, you want:

- a new form2 for each unique "name" param in Send(...)
- all following calls to Send(...) with the same param "name" should add the string in the "body" param to the same list on the associated form2

what about this?

```
Dictionary<string,From2> myForm2s = new Dictionary<string,Form2>();

public void Send(string body, string name)
{
   Form2 frm = null;
   if(!myForm2s.tryGetValue(name,out frm))
   {
      frm = new Form2(body);
      myForm2s[name] = frm;
      frm.Text = name;
      frm.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(Form2_FormClosing);
      frm.Show();
   }
   else
   {
      frm.listBox1.Items.Add(body); // assuming listBox1 is public
      frm.Show();
      frm.BringToFront();
   }
}
void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   e.Cancel = true;
   ((Form2)sender).Hide();
}
```

(code not tested...)

you will possibly want to handle the FormClosing event of Form2 ... cancel the event using the eventarg and call this.Hide() ... so a Form2 will still disappear if the user klicks the x but the form is still there, ready to be reshown when the next event adds something to it ...

Comment: i will test you example. Can you tell me how should i handle the form closing? One more question: can't i make a thread for each new process?

Comment: added FormClosing-Handler ... each new form2 is only a new form ... no new process ... you can make each form run in its own thread, but then you will have to worry about thread sync and which thread may access which control (in .net only the thread that created a control, may access it), so you will have to invoke the right thread do interact with a control ... if you give each form an own process, you will have to deal with inter-process communication ...

Comment: what if the dictionary do not contain the name that is already on desktop then i call the form2 with the help of a thread. Can i do that? I put all the names in a dictionary, but i call a thread each time a new message comes. Can I do that? please help. thx

Comment: that dictionary is empty at startup. each time a send() call executes it looks for the name, and adds to the associated form if it is found ... else it creates a new form with that name, registers it with the dictionary and shows that new form ... there should be no case with a form2 on the desktop that is not in the dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `form2.ShowDialog();`, you can use `form2.Show();`

This works because Show() is modeless, ShowDialog() is modal.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/39wcs2dh%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is an explanation of the differences.

For the second question, as others have said, you can add a form and the name with which it was initiated to a dictionary.  Then, whenever you add another body value, you check the dictionary for a duplicate name value. If one exists, add the body value to the listbox of that particular form.

Answer (score 0):

try to make your form static

```
static Form2 form2;

public void Send(string body, string name)
{        
    form2 = new Form2(body);
    form2.Text = name;
    form2.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary to store the opened Form2 ordered by name:

```
private Dictionary<string, Form2> forms = new Dictionary<string, Form2>();

public void Send(string body, string name)
{
    if(forms.ContainsKey(name))
    {
        forms[name].AddNewItem(body);
    }
    else{
        Form2 form2 = new Form2(body);
        form2.Text = name;
        forms.Add(name, form2);  
        form2.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

And Form2 will contain:

```
public Form2(string s)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    listBox1.Items.Add(s);
}

public void AddNewItem(string s)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(s);
}

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
}
```

Hope this helps :)